Efficiently Grouping Millions of Records by Field in MongoDB - Performance Optimization
I'm working with a large dataset in MongoDB where I need to group approximately 15 million records by a specific field (name). The goal is to find all records where the name field is duplicated. I'm currently using the following aggregation pipeline:
[
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 },
      "records": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "count": { "$gt": 1 }
    }
  }
]

This query works fine for smaller datasets, but it’s becoming problematic with such a large number of records. I'm encountering performance issues, including high memory usage and long execution times.
What I’ve Tried:
Indexing: I've ensured that the name field is indexed to optimize the group operation.
allowDiskUse: I've enabled the allowDiskUse option to permit MongoDB to use temporary files on disk, which helps with large aggregations, but the performance is still suboptimal.
My Questions:
Is there a more efficient way to perform this grouping operation on such a large dataset in MongoDB?
Are there specific techniques or best practices I should be aware of to handle this scale of data?
Would sharding the collection improve performance for this type of query, and if so, how should I go about it?
Are there any MongoDB features or alternative approaches (e.g., MapReduce, batching) that might help manage this operation more effectively?

You can try $setWindowFields to perform grouped count like this. This should be able to leverage your index on name

The query is reading more fields than there are in the index, so it has to fetch all of the documents from disk to satisfy the query.
The group stage is storing the entire original document in an array, so aside from fetching all of the documents from disk, which probably is causing cache pressure, this query will need to hold all 15 million documents in memory simultaneously.
You could reduce the disk bandwidth and memory required for this query by creating an index on {name:1, _id:1}, and returning an array of _id values instead of an array of full documents.
With that index, a query like the following would:

use the index on {name:1, _id:1}
be fully covered by the index,
instead of storing 15 million full documents, would store 15 million ObjectIds (~250MB total).

[
  { 
    "$match": {
       "name": {"$ne": null}
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 },
      "records": { "$push": "$_id" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "count": { "$gt": 1 }
    }
  }
]

Checking with Explain: https://mongoplayground.net/p/o3z6mkiwNwr shows that the query used the index and PROJECTION_COVERED, and did not examine any documents
Without explain: https://mongoplayground.net/p/oh065DKBpzh that query scans 1M documents nearly instantly.
